# How do you add items to a Canvas that is part of a UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have a usercontrol that contains 2 rows.  1st row has a label and 2nd row has a scrollviewer with a canvas:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="TITLE" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="26" />
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <Canvas Background="White" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

In my main window.xaml I'm trying to add this user control and then add items to it's canvas.

```
<local:UserCanvas>
    <label Content="Test" />
</local:UserCancas>
```

There problem here is that when I had that label in there it just overrides the "TITLE" label in row 1 of the user control.  How do I add things so that they are placed on the cavas of the UserControl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining the `Content` in your `UserControl`, define the `UserControl.ContentTemplate`

For example, instead of writing

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        ...
        <Canvas />
        ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

use

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                ...
                <Canvas>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Canvas>
                ...
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.ContentTemplate>
</UserControl>
```

If you use the first syntax, then specifying the Content when you use your UserControl will result in the existing Content getting overwritten, so your rendered Visual Tree ends up looking like this:

```
<local:UserCanvas>
    <label Content="Test" />
</local:UserCancas>
```

By using the 2nd syntax, you're wrapping the Content in your ContentTemplate, so the rendered Visual Tree ends up looking like this:

```
<local:UserCanvas>
    <Grid>
        ...
        <Canvas>
             <label Content="Test" />
        </Canvas>
        ...
    </Grid>
</local:UserCanvas>
```

Comment: This looks like what I have been looking for, however, I have attempted to implement it but have run into a problem.  The <ContentPresenter line is throwing an error the Content after TemplateBinding.  It says: Property 'Content' was not found in type 'Control'.

Comment: That error is there, however, it appears to be working.  My designer will no longer show the User Control, however, it does work.

Comment: @B-Rad I'm always forgetting the exact syntax of the ContentPresenter binding and it takes me a few tests to get it right. Try using `<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}" />` or just `<ContentPresenter />`

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding a public property (that you check and respond to in the user control's `Page_Load()`) and/or public method (that you just call from outside the control) to the user control which you can then access from your main program. Which way to go depends a bit on how complicated the actions you're needing to take will be. It looks to me like this will be simple enough to handle through the public property + `Page_Load()` method.